# form refresh causing URL rewrite to reveal php file

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a problem like this page:

http://www.whichphoneplan.com.au/plans-device-Samsung-Galaxy-S-II.htm

URL is rewritten however, if you select any of the carrier filters, the page refreshes and the URL changes to the name of the PHP file.

Does anyone know how to keep it the same name as it was originally?

Thanks

Comment: The form action attribute points to a php file. It should point to the pretty url.

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit your HTML to point at the correct pages. `mod_rewrite` only rewrites URLs, not your HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL you want to go to instead of the one you don't want to go to:

```
<form name="frmrefresh" id="frmrefresh" method="post" action="plans.php">
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^!
```